# Is it possible to find and eventually catch the starters?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

I have had my starter Cyndaquil on my team my entire play through. Leveled him up all while handling research items along the way. However I got too eager to evolve my Cyndaquil and evolved him with a lot of missing items. I didn't realize at the time that research is on the exact pokemon only, so Quilava has it's own research items.

I want to get Cyndaquil's remaining research items but I can't if I am unable to get another one.

**Is it possible to find another Cyndaquil or any of the other starters in a normal playthough?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be possible to find them in late-game in a

> Space-Time Distortion

**[Rowlet](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rowlet_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Game_locations)**: Coronet Highlands, after beating game (low spawn rate)

**[Cyndaquil](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cyndaquil_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Game_locations)**: Crimson Mirelands, after beating game (low spawn rate)

**[Oshawott](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Oshawott_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Game_locations)**: Alabaster Icelands, after beating game (low spawn rate)

Comment: If you want more sources to back this up, Bulbapedia page for each starter also indicate these locations : [Cyndaquil](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cyndaquil_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Game_locations), [Rowlet](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rowlet_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Game_locations), [Oshawott](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Oshawott_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Game_locations)

Comment: Yeah, I just came across one by chance. Managed to get my Cyndaquil. :)

Comment: @pinckerman While I understand that preference, I would encourage links to Bulbapedia or Serebii when possible - they're much better resources, more likely to be accurate, and not full of ads.

Comment: @Joe totally agree, they are always my first source when possible. I haven't considered ads, so I updated the links.

Answer (score 10):

When you eventually beat the game, you are awarded the other starters from Prof. Laventon but not the one you started with.

Post-game, it seems like they can appear in a space-time distortion. Bumped into a Cyndaquil right in one. You could probably find the others this way too.